# Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, productivity-power-tools

Is there a new version of the Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2012 available? I miss the enhanced scrollbars, the solution navigator and the tabs on the left side (and not on the top) and some other minor features like "Quick Find".

Comment: All of those things are OOTB except the tabs on the left side.

Comment: Like @aclear16, most of the features are already revised and merged as part of Visual Studio 2012. However, features such as tabs on the left side might not appear again. By removing them from Visual Studio 2012, the team seem to indicate they are not qualified for production usage.

The Productivity Power Tools starts as a suite of experimental features, so whether there will be a PPT for Visual Studio 2012 depends on whether Visual Studio team would like to utilize that approach again.

Comment: @aclear16 The enhanced scroll bar is part of VS2012? I don't believe it is, so that makes two things are are not OOTB. This one in particular I'd like to have back.

Comment: I am missing CTRL+Click.

Comment: Missing Alt+Arrow. Very compelling.

Comment: They are not really detailed, but you can stay tuned at *[Productivity Power Tools](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Productivity-Power-Tools/129775143765609)* (at Facebook). *UPDATE* The power tools are out now, see *[Productivity Power Tools 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/11/07/productivity-power-tools-2012.aspx)*.

Comment: Its finally here!!  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd

Comment: Finally pinning as standard.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2012 were released on Nov 7, 2012 - as announced on [The Visual Studio Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/11/07/productivity-power-tools-2012.aspx). Aside from 2010 features, there are several new ones:

- Quick Tasks (instantly perform common tasks - uses `Quick Launch`).
- Power Commands (speeds up how you interact with code)
- Color Printing (now you don't need a separate extension)

Here is a [link to the extensions gallery page](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd).

**Note:** <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> works a bit different. New version reduces tab clutter, which would normally occur after aggressive <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd>ing. VS 2010 would keep all code files open, VS 2012 only keeps the current one, and it's right-aligned (in contrast to other tabs being left-aligned). There is an option to make it permanent, if you need to.

Answer (score 13):

The enhanced scrollbar is not an OOTB feature in visual studio 2012. However, an updated version of the Productivity Power Tools is set to be released in early October. [Source](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728679/useful-features-from-productivity-power-tools-missing)

Comment: Productivity Power Tools for VS2012 have now been released (7th Nov 2012) and available in extension manager. Welcome back Enhanced Scrollbar... :)

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd